# An account I know I'm following is not appearing in the "following" page of my profile

Tags: twitter, follow

I was checking whether or not I followed a particular Twitter account by checking my profile page:

```
https://twitter.com/[account]/following
```

as I couldn't remember what their account was actually called but I knew it would contain at least part of their name. However when I did a search of the page (F3) for their name and it didn't turn up. I made sure I scrolled down to the bottom of the page to make sure I loaded all the data.

I then checked another account that I knew would have retweeted this account or would be following it and when I found the account that way I could see I was following it after all and I was correct in that the account did include the part of the name I was searching for.

Why wouldn't the account show up in my list of who I'm following? Their account isn't protected and I'm not blocked.

I've checked a some other accounts and they don't appear either.